# How to use "cachinnate" in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I don't understand how to use cachinnate in a sentence. Is it correct to say "I'm sorry to cachinnate at you" or "I couldn't stop cachinnating"? How could I use this word in daily life?

Answer (score 7):

## You cannot

> How could I use this word in daily life?

The answer is that you could **not** use this word in daily life. The OED places it in its second-rarest set of words, [Band 2](https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-frequency/):

> Band 2 contains words which occur fewer than 0.01 times per million words
> in typical modern English usage. These are almost exclusively **terms which
> are not part of normal discourse and would be unknown to most people**. Many
> are technical terms from specialized discourses. Examples taken from the
> most frequently attested part of the band include *decanate, ennead,* and
> *scintillometer* (nouns), *geogenic, abactinal* (adjectives), *absterge* and
> *satinize* (verbs). In the lower frequencies of the band, words are uniformly
> strange or exotic, e.g. *smother-kiln, haver-cake,* and *sprunt* (nouns),
> *hidlings, unwhigged, supersubtilized,* and *gummose* (adjectives), *pantle,
> cloit*, and *stoothe* (verbs), *lawnly, acoast,* and *acicularly* (adverbs),
> *whethersoever* (conjunction).

Do you use those words listed above in your daily life? If not, then you cannot use this one there either.

It’s just a rare word that means laugh, from Latin, or these days, laugh far too loudly and perhaps even maniacally like you were off your rocker. It was back-derived during the Victorian Era from the more senior term that antedates it by several centuries in English, [***cacchination***](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/25817), which is also in Band 2 and means laughter that’s unduly loud or crazy.

The only possible way you could ever use these words in daily life is if your daily life only had interactions with extremely hyper-well-educated language geeks who like to show off, particularly those with a background in actual Latin. Otherwise you could not use them because nobody would have any idea what you were talking about.

You occasionally come across it in esoteric tales of eldritch horror.